# choose location manually from autocomplete textview - android

Tags: android, location, manual

I want to make an application, that allows the user to choose his/her location manually through auto-complete text.
I thought that I can make a DB for all countries , cities and their latitudes and longitudes so that the user cant set the location although in offline mode. But I don't know where to get a list of all countries, cities and locations.

I tried to use google places api [google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/query)
but it doesn't return what I want.

Are there any other suggestions to help me get this list ?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "where to get a list of all countries, cities and locations"? Actually you are storing it offline. Then yoy can get it from anywhere(like wiki) Why do you need an API?

Comment: Thanks @HariKrishnan for your reply .. As you suggest I found this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_cities_by_country which contains countries and cities but doesn't have cities locations .. so I have to get the locations manually by searching for each city's location on google ma. I was thinking of something that can provide list of countries , cities and locations to save time.